# What is it called when you add click handlers to links and use Ajax to load sections of the page instead of the whole page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

As the title says I need to find out the name for that method of building websites.

I developed my own javascript to do this but the site does not work when javascript is disabled. Apparently there is a method to make it work using ajax when javascript is enabled and the normal way when javascript is disabled.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here I would be very grateful.

Comment: The method would be to have all your links point to real pages with static content, and use `onclick` handlers to capture clicks and use AJAX instead when possible. Obviously you can't make it client-side; you'll need to set it up on your server (should be easy to do; just make a script which wraps the response you already serve with the site template). As for a name, no idea. Let's call it "Bob's method".

Comment: Yes, that's how the Ajaxify and jNavigate jQuery plugins do it.

Comment: This technique needs a name. I'm going to start calling it ANav for "Ajax Navigation" or "Asynchronous Navigation"

Comment: Or it could be called ANPE for "Ajax Navigation with Progressive Enhancement"

Comment: I like "Bob's Method" best.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for Pagination or Ajaxify